# Dropbox SDK upload timeout error "-1001"

Tags: macos, timeout, synchronization, dropbox

I am trying to use the Dropbox SDK to sync my application, but I have come across a bit of a snag.

On a laptop running OS X Lion the syncing works perfectly fine, it uploads and downloads without a hitch, but when I try it (with the exact same data) on a Mac Pro running Snow Leopard, every single time a couple of files fail to upload. I went into the Console and found this sort of error message for each of the files that didn't upload:

> [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/files_put/sandbox/file.png - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1001 UserInfo=0x2002e8940 "The operation couldn't be completed.
>   (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)"

The upload consists of various file types in a range of sizes.

I rebuilt the SDK with a timeout of 300 seconds, but no luck, it still times out some of the files about 15 seconds after beginning. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

Comment: Kinda, I basically changed my code so I waited until one file had finished uploading before starting the upload of the next file. It was timing out because I told Dropbox to upload all the files at once, figuring it could handle waiting on each request, but it couldn't.

Comment: But it takes lot of time right?

Comment: You're probably running into rate limiting and the SDK is not handling that error case